# typeOf showing incorrect results

Tags: javascript

```
var name = 33;

    if (typeof (name) === 'string') {
        console.log('its a string');
    }
    else if (typeof (name) === 'number') {
        console.log('Number were entered here');

    }
```

**is giving a string from console? how come**??
Thanks.

Comment: try without the `var name = 33;` - you're assigning to a global `window.name`

Comment: variables declared in the global scope are like saying window.variablename = value .. `name` is a standard property of the window object

Comment: Marc, try a different variable name

Comment: @jaromanda thanks.. put it in answer and i will accept it,.,

Comment: window.name is always a string, one of the few special lexical names used by browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variables declared in the global scope are like saying `window.variablename = value` .. `name` is a standard property of the `window` object

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't. See the attached fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/vxy6tt8t/

```
arr = ["test", 1, "3"];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (typeof (arr[i]) === 'string') {
        console.log('its a string');
    } else if (typeof (arr[i]) === 'number') {
        console.log('Number was entered here');
    } 
}
```

To address the comment below. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/d1vhfe67/

```
console.log("original value without declaring var name " + window.name);
var name = 33;

if (typeof name === 'string') {
    console.log('its a string');
} else if (typeof name === 'number') {
    console.log('Number was entered here');
}
```

It is relevant. I understand the global name space but it is important to show that typeOf is actually working as expected. The title is "typeof is giving incorrect results." That is not true. It is giving correct results.

Additionally, the code in his current question gives the correct results. So it would be quite confusing to someone visiting this question later without a persistent example/explanation.

Comment: your example is irrelevant ... the problem is his choice of variable name, namely `name`